# react-toastify not working after build NEXT.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have added `react-toastify` in my `next.js` project. It is working when I run the project using `npm run dev` and after build using `npm run build` and run the same using `npm start` is not working. Is there any additional settings to be made in production to make it work. Please check the below code,

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/scss/main.scss';

function saveAddress() {
    if (!errors) {
        const address = { name, email, phone, addr, city, pincode, landmark, type, token };

        await Axios.post(api.URL_ADD_ADDRESS, {address})
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data.response === 200) {
                dispatch(fetchaddress(token));
                setModalAdd(false);
                toast("Your address added");
            }
            else
                toast("Something went wrong. Tryagain.");
        }).catch(error => {
            toast("Something went wrong. Tryagain.");
        });
    }
}

<ToastContainer
            position="bottom-center"
            autoClose={1500}
            hideProgressBar={true}
            newestOnTop={false}
            closeOnClick
            rtl={false}
            pauseOnFocusLoss
            draggable
            pauseOnHover
            className="toast-container"
        />
```

Is there any additional code need to be added. I have no idea and I have searched a lot. But no solution. Please help me out.

Comment: How did you fix this